# Ubuntu 19.10 - Kabini [Radeon HD 8210]'s vulkan does't seem to work

Tags: 19.10, steam, radeon, gpu-driver, vulkan

At first, I've installed kisak's ppa (as suggested by proton in GitHub). Then, my first attempt of trying out the vulkan support was playing overwatch (via Lutris), but Lutris notified me that vulkan wasn't detected.
After some weak research, I put this command in the terminal "vulkaninfo", this is what it showed me:

```
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
==========
VULKANINFO
==========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.114

/build/vulkan-tools-IZAxVX/vulkan-tools-1.1.114.0+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.c:5884: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

Did I missed some step or I did something wrong?

(As for some "extra info", when a I tried Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer, every time I've installed new kernel, it notifies me that there is some missing firmware for "amdgpu")

Update:
When reinstalling lubuntu 20.04 and updating it (also, kernel update), there's something strange in the terminal

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_smc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_smc.bin for module amdgpu
```

Could this be part of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your card is compatible with Vulkan.
[AMD's website lists HD 8570 and up](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/vulkan)

Comment: That's very strange, as a lot of websites and even AMD support put this card as Vulkan compatible. https://www.amd.com/en/support/apu/amd-e-series-processors/amd-e1-series-apu-for-laptops/e1-2100-radeon-hd-8210